# My posts not updating in my RSS APP

Tags: android, rss

I created an android app to read feed from my blog, but when I added a new post in the blog it is not changing in the app after refresh action.

This is my refresh menu button code, it is working fine but giving the same old data no mater how many times I hit refresh.

```
@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if(item.getItemId()== R.id.menu_refresh) {
        mdialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mdialog.setMessage("Loading Content Please Wait...");
        mdialog.show();

        JsonParse();

//I even specified DatasetChanged(); and still it is not working

        itemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        mqueue.addRequestFinishedListener(new 
        RequestQueue.RequestFinishedListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onRequestFinished(Request request) {
                mdialog.dismiss();
            }
        });



    }

    return true;
}
```

This is my Volley JSON Parsing Code

```
private void JsonParse() {

String url = "https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=http://itzmydarz.blogspot.com/atom.xml";
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {


        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("items");
                for(int i =0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    JSONObject items = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String title = items.getString("title");
                    String date = items.getString("pubDate");
                    String data= items.getString("description");
                   // String imageurl= items.getString("url");
                    webPageItemsList.add(new WebPageItems(data,title,date));

                }

itemsAdapter = new ItemsAdapter(MainActivity.this,webPageItemsList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    mqueue.add(request);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

because your Jsonparse not call that's why

Comment: What? Could u be more clear? I am new to this, but i called my JsonParse() and also put my adapter's DataSetChanged()

Comment: you check first that both data same or not ?

Comment: Actually i used rss2json website to get JSON object from xml url, i think it is showing the same json object even after changing the xml code. is there anyother way to do this?